# Can not to implement filterBy method for TreeStore in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, hide, treestore

I'm following this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29si) which filters `TreePanel`.
My aim is to hide several `TreeStore` items depends on logged account's `username`.

I've used the idea of fiddle on `login` method of my application but now it is showing any of item! How can overcome this situation?

```
login: function (username, password) {
        var me = this;
        var params = {
                // Headers
                'username': username,
                'password': password,
                ...
        };

        var loginReq = {...} // Saves token with a promise function 

        if (username === 'test@useradress.com') {
            var treeStore = Ext.getStore('navMenuTree');

            //debugger; //Error raises on here but doesn't give any error on console.
            treeStore.filterBy(function (item) {
                if (item.get('root') === true) return true;
                else if (item.get('visibleModule') === 1) return true;
                else return false;
            });
        }

        return loginReq;
    },
```

and I've defined TreeStore as mentioned on fiddle;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.NavMenuTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    alias: 'store.navmenutree',

    storeId: 'navMenuTree',
    fields: [{
        name: 'text'
    }],

    root: {
        expanded: true,
        defaultRootProperty: 'data',
        visibleModule: 1, //Here it is.
        data: [
                {
                 text: 'First Menu Item', //Which should be "visible"
                 visibleModule: 1,
                 iconCls: 'x-fa fa-thumbs-up',
                 expanded: false,
                 selectable: false,         

                 data: [
                     {
                        text: translations.dashboard,
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-area-chart',
                        viewType: 'dash',
                        leaf: true,
                        visibleModule: 1 // As well childrens should be visible
                     },
                     {
                        text: translations.bonus,
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-pencil-square-o',
                        viewType: 'bonuslist',
                        leaf: true,
                        visibleModule: 1 //Here also!
                     }
                 ]
                },
                {
                 text: 'Menu Item 2', //Which should be "hide"
                 visibleModule: 2,
                 iconCls: 'x-fa fa-usd',
                 expanded: false,
                 selectable: false,

                 data: [
                    {...}
                 ]
                },
```

Comment: Wow! Unfortunately `if` statments in `login` function is **removing whole `NavMenu` items for different account** as well! =| I couldn't design the function correctly.

Comment: As far as I know, `defaultRootProperty: 'data',` has to be directly on the store, not in the root. Otehr than that, I see no error in your code, maybe you can reproduce in a fiddle.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for comment. I make it working without changing any thing such as `defaultRootProperty` line.

Comment: @Alexander I'll have another question; as I told filtering is working when login to application. But somehow when I reload the page it brings back whole navmenu items back. Is it possible to define `if statment` on `TreeStore` file instead of Login file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've succeed to filter items through mentioned fiddle and on my own structure.

The only thing that raised the issue was `storeId` property of `TreeStore`. It was commented for a unknow reason! When it was not commented then somehow removed whole navigation menu items.

So I've commented it back and used `TreeStore`'s own name on `Ext.getStore()` method. In this way fixed the issue and scenerio works perfectly;

```
if (username === 'test@useradress.com') {
  //Updated only this part. In my case it's Ext.getStore('NavMenuTree')
  var treeStore = Ext.getStore('NameOfTreeStore');

  treeStore.filterBy(function (item) {
    if (item.get('root') === true) return true;
    else if (item.get('visibleModule') === 1) return true;
    else return false;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rootProperty definition should be in store's proxy's reader

ex:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.NavMenuTree', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
  alias: 'store.navmenutree',

  storeId: 'navMenuTree',
  proxy : {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader : {
        type: 'json',
       rootProperty : 'data'
    }
  }
```

Comment: When I set it over `root` property such as you stated, it gives this error: `Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: proxy.undefined`

Comment: I forgot to add type configs I have edited and added as such

Comment: in your case proxy can be memory

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Now I make it working as doing nothing on `TreeStore` expect `storeId`. I'll explain it on my own answer.